# Select Firebase firestore collection where timestamp is today

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, momentjs

Good day everybody,

I have a firetore collection of docs which all have a dateCreated field of timestamp data type. I want to select all the docs where dateCreated is today. How would I achieve this. I have tried below with no success

```
const ref = firestore.collection('orders').where('dateCreated','<',moment().toDate()).orderBy('dateCreated', 'desc');
```

The above line gets all the orders from the collection and I want all the orders that was created today. Hope this makes sense

Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking relative to the user's own timezone and not based on a fixed timezone (e.g. you are on the east coast, but HQ is on the west coast), you can use this:

```
// for numeric timestamp values (milliseconds since 1970-01-01 UTC)
const midnightThisMorning = (new Date()).setHours(0,0,0,0);

const ref = firestore.collection('orders')
  .where('dateCreated', '>', midnightThisMorning)
  .orderBy('dateCreated', 'desc');
```

```
// for firebase.firestore.Timestamp values
const startDate = new Date();
startDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);

const ref = firestore.collection('orders')
  .where('dateCreated', '>', startDate)
  .orderBy('dateCreated', 'desc');
```

If you know that the time must be relative to a particular timezone, you need to calculate midnight based on that timezone instead.

```
// for numeric timestamp values (milliseconds since 1970-01-01 UTC)
const midnightInLA = moment()
  .tz("America/Los_Angeles")
  .startOf("day")
  .valueOf();

const ref = firestore.collection('orders')
  .where('dateCreated', '>', midnightInLA)
  .orderBy('dateCreated', 'desc');
```

```
// for firebase.firestore.Timestamp values
const dateMidnightInLA = moment()
  .tz("America/Los_Angeles")
  .startOf("day")
  .toDate();

const ref = firestore.collection('orders')
  .where('dateCreated', '>', dateMidnightInLA)
  .orderBy('dateCreated', 'desc');
```

**Note:** With `moment-timezone`, if you are only using select timezones you can deploy your code with the details for those timezones rather than all timezones. This process is detailed in [the documentation](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/use-it/webpack/).

Comment: Timezone doesnt really matter as this website is for my local restaurant. However I tried the midnightThisMorning const and I get no records from the orders collection.  Im calling this code from inside a "redux-saga" generator function, but this shouldt affect it right ?

Comment: console.log(midnightThisMorning)  => 1620943200000

Comment: moment().startOf('day').toDate() => seems to do the trick

Comment: Updated the examples to match